# React Google Maps doesn't import

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Sorry, I am new in React.js, and can't understand, why I have next warnings and my code doesnt worl

```
import React from 'react';
import {Map, InfoWindow, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper} from 'google-maps-react';

    class GoogleMap extends Component {   render() {
        return (
          <div className="GoogleMap">
        <Map google={this.props.google} zoom={14}>
          <Marker onClick={this.onMarkerClick} //Unresolved variable onMarkerClick
                  name={'Current location'}/>
          <InfoWindow onClose={this.onInfoWindowClose}> //Unresolved variable onMarkerClick
            <div>
              <h1>{this.state.selectedPlace.name}</h1>
            </div>
          </InfoWindow>
        </Map>
      </div>
    );   } }

export default GoogleApiWrapper({apiKey: (*apikeyhidden*) })(GoogleMap)  //Unused default export
```

and this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; import {GoogleMap} from 'client/src/components/map/google/GoogleMap'; //Element is not exported

class Map extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
          GoogleMap.prototype.render()
        );
    } }

export default Map;
```

My localhost:3000 gives me next:

> Failed to compile ./src/pages/Map.js Module not found: Can't resolve
>   'client/src/components/map/google/GoogleMap' in
>   'C:\Lunch_Time\client\src\pages' This error occurred during the build
>   time and cannot be dismissed.

What is wrong? Please help

Comment: Is `this.onMarkerClick` defined?

Comment: it shoud be defined in 'google-maps-react' library, as I am doing this code from toturial where everything is working

Comment: If it's not defined in your `class` then `**this**.onMarkerClick` isn't defined.

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need a relative path:

```
import {GoogleMap} from './client/src/components/map/google/GoogleMap';
```

or likely

```
import {GoogleMap} from './components/map/google/GoogleMap';
```